# Finding a derivative of the Sine integral

Tags: calculus

> We have a function $$F(x) = \int_{x}^{x^2} \dfrac{\sin t}{t} dt$$ Find $F'(x)$ for $x \in (1, \infty)$.

I was wondering how to do this. The integral $\int \dfrac{\sin t}{t} dt$ can't be written down in terms of elementary functions, I think. So I don't know how to get a meaningful result from that.

Comment: Split the integral into $-\int_a^x+\int_a^{x^2}$; then use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $H(x)=\int_1^x\frac{\sin t}{t}dt$ an antiderivative of the function $t\mapsto \frac{\sin t}{t}$ then 
$$F(x)=H(x^2)-H(x)$$
and by the chain rule you get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

the first derivative is given by $$-{\frac {\sin \left( x \right) }{x}}+2\,{\frac {\sin \left( {x}^{2}
 \right) }{x}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

You can Use Newton, Leibnitz Theorem, for Differentiation under Integral Sign.

$$F(x) = \int_{x}^{x^2}\frac{\sin t}{t}dt\;,$$ Then Differentiate both side w r to $x\;,$ We get

$$\frac{d}{dx}(F(x))= \frac{d}{dx}\left[\int_{x}^{x^2}\frac{\sin t}{t}dt\right] = \frac{\sin x^2}{x^2}\cdot \frac{d}{dx}(x^2)-\frac{\sin x}{x}\cdot \frac{d}{dx}(x)$$

$$F'(x) = \frac{2\sin x^2}{x}-\frac{\sin x}{x}$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: If $$F(x)=\int_{\psi(x)}^{\phi(x)} f(t) dt$$ then $$F'(x)=\phi'(x)f(\phi(x))-\psi'(x)f(\psi(x))$$